# Returning a part of the stdout of a bash command (kpartx)

Tags: regex, string, bash

I want to return the loop device that an image will be mapped to (with kpartx) and store it in a bash variable. For example

```
# kpartx -av wheezy_cln.img 
add map loop0p1 (252:2): 0 131072 linear /dev/loop0 2048
add map loop0p2 (252:3): 0 7825408 linear /dev/loop0 133120
```

should return /dev/loop0 and store it in a bash variable.

I am not very good with regex. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
# capture command output in a
a="`kpartx -av wheezy_cln.img`"
# trim everything before the first / 
a="/${a#*/}"
# trim from the next (first) space 
a="${a% *}"
# result is now in a
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't truly understand your question(sorry) but I'm going to give a try...

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

    if [ "`echo "$line" | grep "/dev/loop0"`" != "" ]; then

        var=`echo "$line" | sed 's/.*loop0 //'`

    fi

    echo "$var"

done < wheezy_cln.img

exit 0
```

**Result:**

2048
133120